# How to encode Json request file using rest-assured in groovy

Tags: rest-assured

```
response = given()
header("Date", dtime).
header("Authorization", auth_header3).
header("Content-MD5", md5).
header("Content-Type", content_type).
body(new File("regcust")).
when().
post("https://"+ipaddress+":"+port+"/v1/clients").
then().
statusCode(201).
extract().
response();
```

Here "regcust" is json file.If i am sending the request with json body,i am getting exception like "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Internal error: Can't encode regcust to JSON."

Answer (score 0):

// set default port for REST-assured
    RestAssured.port = 80;

```
// set default URI for REST-assured.
// In integration tests, this would most likely point to localhost.
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://api.openweathermap.org"
```

### Given Statement to access API.

Given().auth().preemptive().basic(username, password)
                .body(*CONVERT JSON OBJECT IN STRING AND AS PSS HERE*).with().contentType(JSON).when().post(*REST API PATH*);